# Sequelize insert additional fields into junction table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

as described in `sequelize` documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html),

`Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: Baz })`
then there is a method to insert into junction table:

`fooInstance.addBars([5,4])`

It will insert into `Baz` junction table two fields: `FooId,BarId`.
But i need to insert another field value too. sth like this:

`fooInstance.addBars([{BarId: 5, otherField:'xxx'}, ...]`

How i can achieve that without manual insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Advanced Many-to-Many guide](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html).

```
const User_Profile = sequelize.define('User_Profile', {
  selfGranted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, { timestamps: false });
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: User_Profile });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: User_Profile });
```

> With this, we can now track an extra information at the through table, namely the selfGranted boolean. For example, when calling the user.addProfile() we can pass values for the extra columns using the through option.

```
Example:

const amidala = await User.create({ username: 'p4dm3', points: 1000 });
const queen = await Profile.create({ name: 'Queen' });
await amidala.addProfile(queen, { through: { selfGranted: false } });
```

Comment: Yes it can add one Bar, but if i need more, i have to use a ```Promise.all``` concurrent insert, and i can't   use model.addBar``s``, right thinking?
Thanks for your attention and key answer, you saved my mind!

Comment: Try to look at `fooInstance.addBars` signature, maybe it also allows that trick